# Are memory addreses portable in C?

Tags: c, pointers

Say we have program 1...

./program1

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int *i;
  *i = 10;
  printf("%lld", i);
  return 0;
}
```

Now program 2...

./program2 program1output 10

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int *t;
  t = (int*)atoll(argv[1]);
  *t = atoi(argv[2]);
  return 0;
}
```

Will this work? Can you share memory addresses between different programs?

Comment: Short answer: No.

Comment: You could have tried this yourself and seen that the answer is a clear and resounding NO!!!

Comment: In most cases, userspace pointers point to a virtual memory table, which is mapped to physical memory on a lower level. The whole point of this is to avoid 2 processes from accessing the same memory, and to prevent rogue processes from accessing kernel memory...

Answer (score 3):

This behavior is not defined by the C standard. On any general-purpose multi-user operating system, each process is given its own virtual address space. All of the memory assigned to a process is separate from the memory assigned to other processes except for certain shared memory:

- Read-only data may be shared between processes, especially the instructions and constant data of two processes running the same executable and the instructions and constant data of shared libraries. That data may have the same address in different processes or different addresses (depending on various factors, including whether the code is position-independent and whether address space layout randomization is in use).
- Some operating systems also map system-wide shared data into processes by default.
- Memory may be shared between processes by explicit request of those processes to map shared memory segments. Those segments may or may not appear at the same  virtual address in the different processes. (A request to map shared memory may request a certain address, in which case different processes could arrange to use the same address, or it could let the mapping software choose the address, in which case different processes cannot rely on receiving the same address assignment.)

In a special-purpose operating system, different processes could share one address space.

### Supplement

This is not correct code:

```
int *i;
*i = 10;
```

The declaration `int *i;` defines `i` to be a pointer but does not assign it a value. Then using `*i` is improper because it attempts to refer to where `i` points, but `i` has not been assigned to point to anything.

To define an `int` and make its address visible in output, you could define `int i;` and then print `&i`.

This is not the proper way to print an address:

```
printf("%lld", i);
```

To print an address, cast it to `void *` and format it with `%p`. The result of the formatting is implementation-defined:

```
printf("%p", (void *) &i);
```

This is not a good way to reconstruct an address:

```
int *t;
t = (int*)atoll(argv[1]);
```

As with `printf`, the type should be `void *`, and there are problems attempting the conversion with `atoll`. The C standard does not guarantee it will work; the format produced by printing with `%p` might not be a normal integer format. Instead, use the `%p` specifier with `sscanf`:

```
void *temp;
if (1 != sscanf(argv[1], "%p", &temp))
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
int *t = temp;
```

When the address comes from other process, the behavior of the `sscanf` conversion is not defined by the C standard.

Comment: Why is the `void*` cast necessary?

Comment: @Ayxan: The C standard permits pointers of different types to have different representations, and pointers of different types are generally not compatible with each other as defined by the C standard. Per C 2018 7.21.6.1 8, the proper type for an argument corresponding to a `%p` conversion is `void *`. Passing the wrong type results in behavior not defined by the C standard. Practically, in an implementation where the passed type had a different representation from `void *`, it would be misinterpreted at best or could corrupt the stack frame and bollux the program completely.

Answer (score 0):

In principal, an application operates on its own/private memory. There are ways of sharing memory among different processes, but this requires special mechanism to overcome above mentioned "principal" (memory mapped files, for example). Have a short look at, for example, [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/279128/how-to-share-memory-between-applications-written-in-c-c) article on sharing memory.

In your case, program one will have ended and its memory is not available any more; and the way you access it is definitely not one of the "special mechanisms" necessary to access shared memory:

Though an integer vale may be converted to a pointer value, accessing this pointer is only valid if the integer value has originally been converted from a pointer to a valid object. This is not the case in your example, since the integral value calculated in `t = (int*)atoll(argv[1]);` never pointed to a valid object in the current program.

Answer (score 0):

In general, memory addresses are tied to processes because each process may have its own memory space. So, the addresses are virtual addresses rather than physical addresses, which means they are references to a location in the process's memory space rather than references to a location on a chip.

(Not all environments have virtual memory. For example, an embedded system might not.)

If you have two programs running in the same process, a pointer can be passed between them. For example, a main program can pass a pointer to a dynamically linked library it loads.

---